# How can you minimize IOPs in a MongoDB Replica Set?

Tags: mongodb

We're running into IOPs limits (largely writes) on our hardware for a replica set cluster. What kinds of knobs and levers can we pull to buy time through the end of the year before we migrate to a sharded cluster?

WAL tuning? (Write to it less often?)

I assume mongo "batch" operations just minimize network activity, not so much disk.

There may be rampant write amplification based on the indexes involved? Compression in the storage engine? Are their handy ways to measure all of this?

Comment: You can play with compression, but the chances are you already have snappy. switching to zlib should improve compression and marginally reduce disk IO for the cost of higher CPU usage. The only significant improvements you can achieve only by reducing number of replicas. i.e. reducing from 3 to 2 will save you some 20-25% of writes for the cost of compromised resilience and increased risk of data loss. Sharding is a tricky topic.   At some point it will start re-balancing = a lot of writes.

Comment: In our case each instance has its own (throttled) storage, how would reducing the instance count reduce the load on any given instance? Is there some extra overhead per replica?

Comment: No, in this case it won't help.